# BigCommerce - how to add an extra column in the category page layout?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am new to this so I hope my question is relevant and useful to others.

I have a bigcommerce store and I removed the side category display panel from the category page (I did not want a side category to dispay) but this has now left me with only 4 columns of products displayed on a page 5 columns wide. Could any kind person tell me how to add an extra column of products, so that the page width is full again, or how to alter the image size so that 4 columns of product images fills the space previously occupied by 4+sidecategory ?

Comment: Question: do you use Bigcommerce Stencil? or do you use Blueprint?

Answer (score 1):

To change the layout of your category page you require to do change in `category.html`. As per your requirement you need to remove the below code from the `category.html` (Any change in this file will reflect in all your category pages)

```
<div class="Left fleft">
     %%SNIPPET_SubCategories%%
     %%Panel.SideCategoryShopByPrice%%
 </div>
```

I am saying to remove the entire side column div because you want the full page layout but you can just remove the particular snippets or panels which you don't want but with that sometime what happens is like any panel which is currently not active from admin panel but later whenever it will active then it shows the problem like your layout will display with side column having that particular panel and also your wide column (products column) with 5 products in a row.

After this you have to do change in css file named `styles.css`, In this file search for the `.ProductList li` in which you can see the width which is given in percentage to `25` so please make it to `20`.

Please save the above files and you can see the changes.

Thanks.